# About the weak* closedness of the kernel of a continuous linear functional

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

I will appreciate any help on the following:

Let $X$ be any Banach space (complex or real) and $\varphi\in X^{**}$ with the property that $\ker(\varphi)$ is weak$*$ closed. I want to prove that $\varphi\in J[X]$, where $J:X\to X^{**}$ is the canonical injection $J(x)(f)=f(x)$, for $f\in X^*$.

I know it is proved in "Brezis - Functional Analysis,
Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations" Corollary 3.15, but what bothers me that they assume the space is real, and I fail to use the main idea there for the complex case.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: One can split the proof into two parts: 1. A linear functional is continuous if (and, of course, only if) its kernel is closed. 2. The dual of $X^*$ endowed with the weak$*$ topology is $J(X)$. Both parts are true for complex Banach (and, more generally, locally convex) spaces.

Comment: Another idea is to use the real case and write $\varphi(x)= \Re \varphi(x) + i \Im \varphi(x) = \Re \varphi(x) - i \Re(i \varphi(x)) = \Re \varphi(x) - i  \Re \varphi(ix)$

Comment: Thank you very much, both ideas were very helpful.